# Are there Spanish equivalents for "turtle" and "tortoise"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, animales, terminología, ciencia, polisemia

In (British) English, marine "turtles" are distinguished from terrestrial "tortoises".<sup>1 2</sup>

In Spanish, both of these groups of reptiles come under the blanket term [*tortuga*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a8iZjLF).

**Are there any analogous Spanish terms for "tortoise" and "turtle"?**

Similar to how though "owl" describes both *búho* and *lechuza* in English, there exist the more specific terms ["true/typical owl"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_owl) and ["barn owl"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn-owl) respectively.

---

<sup>1. In layman's terms, i.e. not scientific nomenclature.</sup>
<sup>2. Sometimes freshwater/brackish water turtles are further distinguished as "terrapins".</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### General terms

Turtles, terrapins, and tortoises can be identified respectively by the Spanish terms:

| English | Spanish |
| --- | --- |
| Turtle | *tortuga marina* *tortuga de mar* |
| Terrapin | *[tortuga dulceacuícola](https://reptiles.paradais-sphynx.com/informacion/diferencias-tortugas-marinas-dulceacuicolas-terrestres.htm)* *[tortuga de agua dulce](http://www.acherpetologia.org/images/doc/Cartilla_tortus_manejo_decomisos.pdf)* |
| Tortoise | [*galápago*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IindpzQ)<sup>1 2</sup> *tortuga terrestre* |

### Scientific terms

Veering into more zoological terminology, you also have:

- [quelonio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UmgDoHL) "chelonian" (i.e. any *tortuga*)
- [emídido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EirG12d) "terrapin" (any species of the family [*Emydidae*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emydidae))<sup>3</sup>

---

**Notes:**
<sup>**1.** In Ecuador, [*galápago*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IindpzQ) refers specifically to the Galápagos giant tortoise, not terrapins.</sup>
<sup>**2.** According to [Corominas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal%C3%A1pagos_(desambiguaci%C3%B3n)#cite_note-1) *galápago*'s ultimate etymology possibly comes from a pre-roman hispanic term for any shelled creature/thing, and that it is cognate with *calabazo* (pumpkin) and *carapacho/caparazón* (turtle shell).<sup>4</sup></sup>
<sup>**3.** The similarly named [*emidosaurio*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Eis2h2F) refers to a group of crocodilians (caimans). This similarity comes from its dubbing as a 'terrapin' lizard (for the ossofied scales on its back resembling a terrapin's shell).</sup>
<sup>**4.** There is a surprising variety in the names one can give to a turtle's shell (carapace): *[garapacho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IsJnmM6), [carapacho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7Qj21O2), [caparazón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7HsQd4w), [carroncho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B0D49Sg) (Hond.), [concha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A81xUaG), [coraza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AoXZDhy), casco, [espaldar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GTS0e0x) & [peto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SpzmeVn)/[plastrón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TLusxvN) etc*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> Supplementary answer on regional terms.

## Regional terms

The confusion between the British, American and Australian usage of the words turtle/tortoise etc<sup>1 2 3</sup> stems from the different fauna encountered in each region. Naturally in Spanish too certain dialects have their own words for different species and groups of species of *tortuga*.

Many of the following terms, though specifically used for certain species, also serve in the dialects where they are used (via metonymy) as synonyms for any *tortuga* or any sea-turtle/river-turtle/tortoise:

### Tortoises

| English | Spanish | Image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Galápagos tortoise | [galápago](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gal%C3%A1pago) (Ec.) | [image] |
| Red-footed tortoise / Yellow-footed tortoise | [morrocoy](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=morrocoy) (Pa, PR, Co, Ve, Ec.) [morrocota](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=morrocota) (Co.) [morrocoyo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=morrocoyo) (Pa, Co:N) [tequeteque](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tequeteque) (Ve.) | [image] |
| Red-footed tortoise | [peta](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=peta) (Bo:E.) [tortuga de tierra](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tortuga) (Bo:E.) | [image] |

### Terrapins

| English | Spanish | Image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Terrapin | [jarico](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jarico) (Cuba) |  |
| South American Snapping turtle | [tortuga mordedora](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tortuga) (Ec.) | [image] |
| Mata mata | [jicotea](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=jicotea), [hicotea](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=hicotea) (Mx:SE, RD, PR, Co, Ve.) `Taino` [icotea](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=icotea) (Ho, ES, Pa, RD, Co, Ve.) [matamata](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=matamata) (Co, Ec, Pe:E.) | [image] |
| D'Orbigny's slider | [morrocoy](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=morrocoy), [morrocoyo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=morrocoyo) (Ur.) | [image] |
| South American River turtle | [charapa](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=charapa) (Co, Ec, Pe) [galápaga](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gal%C3%A1paga) (Co:E,S.) [tortuga arrau](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tortuga) (Co, Ec.) [tortuga sabanera](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tortuga) (Co) | [image] |
| Yellow-spotted river turtle | [capitari](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=capitari) (Pe.) [terecay](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=terecay) (Co, Ve.) [taricaya](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=taricaya) (Co, Ec, Pe.) [tartaruga](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tartaruga) (Ec, Bo:E.) [tortuga de agua](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tortuga) (Bo:E.) | [image] |

### Sea turtles

| English | Spanish | Image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hawksbill sea turtle | [carey](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=carey) (Mx, Ho, Cu, RD, PR; f. Pa.) `Taino` [caray](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=caray) (RD.) [peje colorado](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=peje) (PR.) | [image] |
| Loggerhead sea turtle | [caguama](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6cyP0bz) (Mx, Ho, Ni, Cu, Co, Ve; *m.* PR, rur; *m.* Pa.) `Caribe` [cahuama](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cahuama) (Mx.) [[tortuga] camagua](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tortuga) (Ho, Ni.) `náhuatl camahuac` [cabezona](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cabezona) (Ni.) | [image] |
| Leatherback sea turtle | [tora](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tora) (Ho, Ni.) [laúd](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=la%C3%BAd) (Mx, Ho, Ni, Pa.) [baula](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5EYLt0q) (Ho, CR) [tinglado](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tinglado) (Cu.) | [image] |
| Green sea turtle | [jaco](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=jaco) (Cu.) [tortuga verde](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tortuga) (Ho, PR, Ec.) [carey blanco](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=carey), [peje blanco](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=peje) (PR.) | [image] |

---

**Source:**

<sup>*[South American Tortoises](http://www.iucn-tftsg.org/wp-content/uploads/file/Articles/Vinke_etal_2008%5Bpart%5D.pdf)*</sup>

**Notes:**

<sup>1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortoise#Terminology</sup>
<sup>2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle#Turtle,_tortoise,_or_terrapin</sup>
<sup>3. [*The Greatest Show on Earth*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=U8AFxmc76rcC&q=tortoise#v=snippet&q=tortoise&f=false), Dawkins (p.174)</sup>

> <sup>Before going any further, I can't escape a tiresome point of terminology, and a regrettable vindication of George Bernard Shaw's observation that 'England and America are two countries divided by a common language'. In Britain, turtles live in the sea, tortoises live on land and terrapins live in fresh or brackish water. In America all these animals are 'turtles, whether they live on land or in water. 'Land turtle' sounds odd to me, but not to an American, for whom tortoises are the subset of turtles that live on land. Some Americans use 'tortoise' in a strict taxonomic sense to refer to the Testudinidae, which is the scientific name for modern land tortoises. In Britain, we'd be inclined to call any land-dwelling chelonian a tortoise, whether it is a member of the Testudinidae or not (as we shall see, there are fossil 'tortoises' that lived on land but are not members of the Testudinidae). In what follows, I'll try to avoid confusion, making allowance for readers in Britain and America (and Australia, where the usage is different again), but it's hard. The terminology is a mess, to put it mildly. Zoologists use 'chelonians' for all these animals, turtles, tortoises and terrapins, whichever version of English we speak.</sup>

<sup>As you can see from this diagram (p.177), aquatic chelonians ("turtles") is not monocladistic:</sup>

[image]